# iPhone : How to hide code of static library while debug in simultor

Tags: iphone, static-libraries

I have built a static library which I am using into one application. The static library is built for iPhone device and simulator and created universal library

When I used it in application everything works well. I could debug the library from application using line by line debug method in simulator mode.

While debug xcode is showing the code of the library which I want to hide during debug.

Is there any way to do this? Any command or method to remove code from library.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Don't deliver the source code to the clients? ;)

Comment: hummm that's true man... please help me if you have any other idea.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `Generate Debug Symbols` in Build Settings of that target. You need to set it to `NO`.